# VS2013 process cannot access the file because it is being used by anther process

Tags: asp.net-mvc, visual-studio

I have VS2013 with UPDATE 2 RC installed. 
I just created a new MVC project.  Compiled and Run has no problem.
I did a small change on the Home/Index.cshtml view.  click save and getting message as

> "The process cannot access the file
>   'C:\Temp\TestMVC\TestMVC\Views\Home\xwfz25mf.3dn~' because it is being
>   used by another process."

.   I really don't understand it.   I am trying to save the file index.cshtml, not 'xwfz25mf.3dn~'  file.  I keep consistently getting similar errors when saving other pages.

before installing the "UPDATE 2 RC", vs2013 worked just fined.  no problem with saving files at that time.

Can someone please help and let me what's in the "UPDATE 2 RC" which doesn't allow me to save any files at all!.  Thanks.!

Comment: Try closing and reopening VS, then make your change and try saving again

Comment: closed vs project re-opened vs project, same issue. same error message.   This is very weird.   Something is locking up all the project files

Comment: Are you using a Mac with Desktop Parallels VM running Windows by any chance?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with my VS2013 ASP.NET MVC project.

At the end I found that the problem was Skype using port 80.

Closing (quit) Skype it worked!